# Inheritance and constricted referencing

Tags: python, uml, inheritance

Let's say I have `BaseA` and `BaseB` classes. `BaseB` can have to several references of `BaseA` instances. Now, we have two other classes, `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` that respectively inherit from `BaseA` and `BaseB`.

[image]

How can I show in such a diagram that `DerivedB` should only store instances of `DerivedA` and not instances of `BaseA`? It seemed pretty simple before I tried to draw it, but now I'm confused. One obvious answer would be "redesign your code"; if there is no alternative, I will probably try to do so.

Comment: make the type in derived B as has many of DerivedA ? does not matter that Derived A's base class is BaseA. As far as DerivedB is concrned it has variables of type 'DerivedA'

Comment: @tgkprog Well, since I am using Python, If I feed `DerivedB` some `BaseA`, those instances will not automagically be converted to `DerivedA`. When I think about it again, it may be more a "contract" with the programmer than a strict design...

Comment: @Morwenn: I am not a Python export, but in other languages you would just create BaseA as an abstract base class, so you cannot have any instances of BaseA which are not also a "DerivedA". Perhaps this concept http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html is similar?

Comment: @DocBrown Hum, I never had to use this module before, I will have a look :)